# If there are spaces in the string, it will be Line change in react-native

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i am using react-native with styled-components

If you type a string in the text and press space, it will be Line change or create a two-much space.

like this image

[image]

I've only used spaces once or twice in the image. But the line breaks like this:

this is my code

```
    const Container = styled.View`
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 1% 2% 0 2.5%;
      border-bottom-width: 0.8px;
      border-color: #c6cfc7;
    `;

    const CommentContainer = styled.View`
      padding: 4.5% 2% 3.5% 5%;
      margin-top: 0.5%;
    `;

    const SecondCommentCon = styled.View`
    `;


    const LabelContainer = styled.View`
      background: lightblue;
      width: 100%;
    `;

    const Label = styled.Text`
      background: lightcoral;
      padding-top: 3.5%;
      line-height: 18px;
      top: 0.5%;
      font-size: 13px;
    
    `;

      return (
        <>
          <Container>
          <CommentContainer>
              <SecondCommentCon>
                <LabelContainer>
                  <Label>{item.content}</Label>
                </LabelContainer>
              </SecondCommentCon>
              </CommentContainer>
          </Container>
        </>
      );
    };
    export default TodoItem;
```

How can I modify my code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wrapped-text
supports korean language